# Node Commander.js catching options passed to Mocha when running tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mocha.js, node-commander

I've recently introduced `commander.js` to a project and use it in various scripts to parse CLI arguments. I'll give one example of where it's been used:

```
const { program } = require('commander');

program
    .description('Import customers and accounts')
    .argument('[filePath]', 'Path to JSON file containing customers and accounts', `${path.resolve(__dirname)}/data/customers.json`)
    .action(filePath => {
        importCustomersAndAccounts(filePath)
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
            process.exit();
        })
        .finally(() => process.exit());
    })

program.parse();
```

This script itself isn't the issue, it works fine when run from the CLI. The issue happens when I run tests that use this same script. I have the test script setup in `package.json` as follows:

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=TESTING mocha --exit --require tests/setup.js 'tests/src/**/*.spec.js' 'tests/scripts/**/*.spec.js'"
```

When I run the tests, I immediately get this error:

```
error: unknown option '--exit'
```

Which is being thrown by commander, not mocha. So this option getting passed to mocha when running `npm run test` is getting to the script itself. I've confirmed this is what's happening, because when I chained `.option('--exit')` after the `.description()` in the commander code above, it then failed with

```
error: unknown option '--require'
```

So it's reaching the next option passed to mocha and then failing on whichever option is not defined in the script. How can I prevent these options from reaching the script itself and get them to simply be parsed by mocha?

Comment: I think you've to test whether your app is actually being called from the terminal and manually call the `program.parse()` with `process.argv`. Or may be like `if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== "TESTING") program.parse()`.

Comment: @h-sifat Yes, that seems to be what the issue was here. When conditionally calling `program.parse()` ensuring the script is being run from the CLI and not imported, there are no longer any errors. Please feel free to post this as an actual answer so I can accept it as correct. Thank you!

Comment: No, it's ok. I'm just glad that it fixed your problem. I'm happy of help.